# Setting variables in application.properties, the build fails

Tags: quarkus

In application.properties I want to use variables as below.

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=${DATASOURCE_DB_KIND}
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://${DB_URL}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_DATABASENAME}?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory&sslmode=require
quarkus.datasource.username=${DB_USERID}
quarkus.datasource.password=${DB_PWD}
```

But when I run a build

```
./mvnw clean package
```

getting error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.5.2.Final:build (default) on project graphql-mp: Failed to build quarkus application: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Property DATASOURCE_DB_KIND not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fails because you didn't define the environment variable `DATASOURCE_DB_KIND`.

If you want it to be able to work without one defined, you need to set a default value and use something like `${DATASOURCE_DB_KIND:yourdefaultvalue}`.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume. the changes worked.

in application.properties
DEFAULTVALUE=mydefault
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://${DB_URL:${DEFAULTVALUE}}:${DB_PORT:${DEFAULTVALUE}}/${DB_DATABASENAME:${DEFAULTVALUE}}
quarkus.datasource.username=${DB_USERID:${DEFAULTVALUE}}
quarkus.datasource.password=${DB_PWD:${DEFAULTVALUE}}

Comment: All the variable values are loaded into the env with a configmap

Comment: Thanks man. I were debugging it for hours now. Seems like quarkus wants a default for all of those variables which are required during build time. While i now have a default in place it still inserts the var of my pipeline. Without the default the error keeps promting.

Comment: What happens if at runtime the ENV var has a different value? In my case it's not taken into account